# a question about package in TCL

Tags: package, tcl

I have a question about package in TCL

I have a test1.tcl file:

```
package provide hello 0.1.0


set globalVariable 20
```

this file in required in test2.tcl

```
package require hello 0.1.0

puts $globalVariable
```

and the pkgIndex.tcl is:

```
package ifneeded hello 0.1.0 [list source [file join $dir test1.tcl]]
```

when I execute the test2.tcl, it tells me, the package hello 0.1.0 is not found.

I try to execute the pkgIndex.tcl, it tells me can not read variable dir, all of these three files are under the same folder. how could I fix it? can anyone help?

Comment: You'd be best writing `set ::globalVariable 20` or putting it all in `namespace eval`, as that stops a whole range of possible surprises with cross-interactions between different parts of your program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read the documentation for `pkg_mkIndex` which explains how the interpreter goes about looking for packages to load.  The short version is:

> Install the package as a subdirectory of one of the directories given
>   by the `tcl_pkgPath` variable. If you install the package anywhere else,
>   then you must ensure that the directory containing the package is in
>   the `auto_path` global variable or an immediate subdirectory of one of
>   the directories in auto_path.

Comment: @ratzip, make sure you're setting the global variable `auto_path`, that is, try `set ::auto_path ...` to be sure.  Feel free to consult the parallel thread about globals ;-)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Glenn and Jackson answer: The Tcl interpreter also looks at the TCLLIBPATH environment variable, so set it up to point to your directory containing the package. More information here: http://wiki.tcl.tk/1787. I usually put these lines in my bash start-up file:

```
TCLLIBPATH="$TCLLIBPATH ~/path/to/my/package"
export TCLLIBPATH
```

Answer (score 1):

In 'test2.tcl', before executing `package require`, add this:

```
lappend auto_path [file dirname [file normalize [info script]]]
```

Then, Tcl can look in your current directory for the pkgIndex file.

Comment: Even better is to use `lappend auto_path [file dirname [info script]]`